# Issue with sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, asus, soundcard

I have tried everything, from reinstalling the drivers to pulseaudio. The sound is playing but I cannot hear anything. The volume is at max and nothing is muted. Can someone please help me ?[image]

Comment: Do you have any other audio output device?

Comment: Not at all, this is the only one. I just don't get it, it doesn't make any sense. I'm on dual boot.

Comment: Have you tried headphones?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka headphones works fine but not internal speakers

Comment: `sudo apt install pavucontrol` is this mixer useful?